# Error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dimensions

The following code works when I run it on its own:

```
range = multi_sptime(100,end);
binary_input = binary_input2(1:range);
ssignal = signal(1:range);
signal = ssignal;% input current
clear input2 
clear binary_input2
dbstop if error
```

However, when I add this `for` loop:

```
neurons=[1,2,4,6,8,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,100,200];
for ncell=neurons
...
```

I get the error below:

> `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
>   Error in int_idc20 (line 8)
>
>   ssignal = signal(1:range);`

How do I fix it and what's going on?

Comment: Could you please narrow down the code? Also, the error happens before the loop, so do you have an outer loop?

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you wanted to loop over the # of elements in `neurons` , so correct your `for` line with:

```
for ncell=1:numel(neurons)
```

and then depending on what you want use `ncell` or  `neurons(ncell)` in your loop.

Second, `range` is a scalar that looks for `multi_sptime` row # 100 last element, and apparently the number it spits is larger than the  # of  elements is  `signal`. Try to `size(signal)` to see what you have.